# import an existing typescript project into visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I already have a typescript project I've been working on outside of visual studio 2013. I'm wanting to make the move to vs2013 now, but I can't seem to get my files to be imported. How would I go about this? I have a large application with deeply nested folder structure running on a grunt build system.

I have tried creating a new typescript project and manually adding the files, but it doesn't auto-add with folders, and I dont' want to manually create all the folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Visual Studio Solution Explorer you have a few buttons on the top. One of them is "Show All Files". After you click that button, you see all the files and folder which are in the same folder as your typescript project.

You can right click a folder and say "Include in Project" to add them all at once.